# Mongo mapReduce, multiple source collections, conditionally include values from existing key

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have multiple collections and am creating a single information collection via mapReduce based on both of their contents.  in my reduce method, how can I apply conditional logic based on the source collection or if its a previously existing key from the output collection.

When reducing collection A into the information collection:

- I want to sum values from a subset of fields that are specific to the input collection and overwrite those fields. I do not want the values from an existing key in the information collection to be included in the sum.
- If the key exists in the information collection, I want to overwrite just those fields, preserving the values of other fields if the key exists.

When merging collection B into the information collection:

- I want to conditionally overwrite with a subset of fields from collection B
- Preserving the values of other fields if the key exists.

**Currently I am trying the following:**

- I have a map function for each of the source collections that emits a uniform value. The emitted value has a field "source" which indicates which collection it is from.
- I have a single reduce function. The first thing it does is create a object structured like the uniform value.
- I have a finalize function that sets the source field to 'final', indicating an existing key.
- The reduce function checks the source value, and tries to discern which logic to use. If Collection A it does the sums, if B it replaces, if Final it tries to follow the merge logic.
- I run the mapReduce using the reduce option, to update keys.

**The Problem**

- I recently realized that finalize will be called multiple times. This eliminates my ability to discern what logic I should be applying in the reduce.
- How do I apply conditional logic based on the source collection or if its a previously existing key in my reduce method?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I apply conditional logic based on the source collection or if its a previously existing key in my reduce method?

To do this, you need data from the "information" collection to be included in the data sent to reduce(). For this, output with the "reduce" action. See [Output to a Collection with an Action](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#output-to-a-collection-with-an-action). After reducing data from collection A (or B), the "reduce" action instruct Mongo to then reduce the intersection (by key) of this data and records in your output collection.

If your map() generates keys that already exist in the "information" collection, reduce will be run on the new records (from A or B) and the existing records (from "information"). Obviously, this will mean your reduce function becomes more complex, but at least you have all the data you need to apply your conditional logic.

Comment: Right, thats what I am doing. The problem is how does one know which is a new record and which is pre-existing?